# Line from left side of screen to end of centered div

Tags: css, html

I want to make a 1 px line from the left side of the screen to the end of a centered `div`.
The `div` is centered with `margin: auto;`.

This image shows how it should look:

[image: example]

Comment: You can use a <hr /> tag but you would need to know the length of the div/where it stops.

Comment: Can you please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your markup ?

Comment: I know the width of div but i cant do it like that becouse i would have to know the left margin which is not constant

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GvFPq/ thats all...

Comment: @user2075220 Hope you have a chance to look at my approach, turns out there's a simple CSS solution for your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is another solution and it is cross browser http://jsfiddle.net/9qrSy/3

```
<div class="inner"></div>
<div class="wrapp"></div>

css 



   body {
    padding:8px;
}
div.wrapp {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:2px solid green;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}
div.wrapp:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:1px;
    right:0;
    top:-6px;
    background:blue;
    z-index:1;

}
.inner {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    height:1px;
    left:0;
    top:12px;
     background:blue;


}
```

Comment: You can see how this works if you change `top:-5px` to `top:5px`. The blue line is made up of two overlapping lines: a line from the left edge of the window to the center, and a line from the left edge of the `div` to the right edge.

Comment: Zoom out the screen and it breaks, I would prefer @Vucko's solution, but again, support is dicey..

Comment: @Hushme not as handy as mine

Comment: @koala_dev we are trying to achieve same thing with different method i like all methods they are all good including yours too

Comment: Well I would argue that we are looking for the most optimal solution that achieves that goal

Comment: if you say that than i can say that you are using very large width can also be failed on very large screen with parent div very small

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example using [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
.box{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.line{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: calc(((100% - 200px)/2) + 200px);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yCrAx/)

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: is it possible to do it without calc?

Comment: You'll need to calculate the `width` somehow so without using `calc` I doubt it's possible ( for a pure **CSS** solution ). But if can use JavaScript, then you can calculate the width easily.

Comment: Actually a pure CSS solution turned out to be pretty simple, check my answer

Comment: @koala_dev I prefer not using `absolute` positioning.

Answer (score 5):

How about this solution? no extra markup needed, cross browser and does not depend on the width of the element

```
#content {
    width:400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin:auto;
    position: relative;
}

#content:before{
    content: '';
    height: 1px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: 0;
    width: 999%; /*a large number*/
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GvFPq/3/)**

Comment: when page is zoomed out in chrome its break out

Comment: that's because the line is 1px tall, if you need to support all zoom levels then I would suggest setting the height to at least 2px

Comment: yes i told you that all method are good and i really enjoying people post here they are giving multiple solution to the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works in all browsers, but I believe `hr` takes up all the space you provide it with. Therefore you can give it a large negative left-margin and put it inside the centered div. Instead of a hr-element, you could use an empty div too, which might or might not be easier to use. You can set the `border-top` style of that div to a wider range of border-types (dotted for example).

```
<div id="content">
    <hr id="bar" />
    <div id="realcontent">    
        Something here
    </div>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
#content {
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
}

#bar {
    margin-left: -1000px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: blue;
}

#realcontent {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```